# Recursion in Python and Scala

Tags: python, scala, recursion, activation-record

Why does this Scala recursion

```
def foo(id:Int): Int = { 
    if (id == 0) { return id } else { foo(id - 1) }
}
foo(2)
```

returns `0`, while this Python recursion returns `None`?

```
def foo(id):
    if id == 0:
        return id
    else:
        foo(id - 1)
foo(2)
```

In which way do Python and Scala handle recursion and manage nested activation records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Scala, any block is evaluated to the value of it's **last statement**. For example, you can write:

```
val myVal = {
  val t = 1
  val r = 8
  t + r
}
```

Here, `myVal` would evaluated to `9`.

Similarly, your `else` block evaluates to the value returned from `foo(id - 1)` (even though there's no explicit `return` keyword), and therefore the value of the entire method body would evaluate to that value as long as the `else` block is reached (the entire `if` statement would be evaluated to the result of `foo(id - 1)`, and since that `if` is the last (and only) statement in the method body - that would be the method's return value).

You can drop the first `return` keyword as well:

```
def foo(id:Int): Int = { 
  if (id == 0) id else foo(id - 1)
}
```

In Python, that's simply not the case; Only `return` statements signify the method's return value. If you return nothing, `None` is returned.

Answer (score 1):

You need `return` in your `else` clause:

```
def foo(id):
    if id == 0:
        return id
    return foo(id - 1)
```

This is with `return` you are basically assigning a value to the function. And two, Scala does an evaluation at the last statement while Python requires the `return` keyword. So if `foo(0)` returns 0, `foo(0)` will then *contain* the value of 0. Since *nothing* is returned, the function doesn't have any value, which defaults to `None`.

By using `return`, you are assigning the value of `foo(id-1)` to `foo(id)`. But what is it? This is where it gets recursive since to get the value of `foo(id-1)`, it must run the function. This happens over and over until you get 0. In other words with `return`:

```
foo(n) = foo(n-1) = foo((n-1)-1) = foo(n-2) = ... = foo(n-n) = foo(0) = 0
```

You can watch the steady decrease of `id`/`n` [here](https://repl.it/Jo62/4).

Answer (score 0):

You either need to add a `return` to the `else` clause:

```
def foo(id):
    if id == 0:
        return id

    return foo(id - 1)
```

or do something like:

```
def foo(id):
    return id if id == 0 else foo(id - 1)
```

Comment: I understand that in this way both Scala and Python solutions return the same result, but why do I need to add the second return statement? Which is the difference in the way these recursions are handled?

Comment: @w4bo, Scala does an *implicit* return of the last expression.  Python doesn't, so we have to add an *explicit* return.  The recursions are likely handled the same.